# Smart pointers inside classes?

Tags: c++, class, smart-pointers

I'm having a following example of class template:

```
template<class T>
class MyContainer{
public:
    T* myArray;
    int size;
    MyContainer(int n) : size(n){
        myArray = new T[n];
    }
    ~MyContainer(){
        delete[] myArray;
    }
};
```

Is it possible to use smart pointers like unique_ptr or shared_ptr for **myArray** so I don't need to deallocate it in destructor? How?

Comment: Why not `template <typename T> using MyContainer = std::vector<T>`?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: What is the problem? Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: How can I do it? How do I change a raw pointer T with the smart-one?

Comment: If the size cannot be changed I suggest to use a `std::array`(C++11)

Comment: @MassimoCosta: `n` is an argument to the constructor, so `std::array` is inapplicable.

Comment: I know, but I suggested to change interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, and you really should :

```
template<class T>
class MyContainer{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> myArray;
    int size;
    MyContainer(int n) : myArray(new T[n]), size(n) { }
};

int main() {
  MyContainer<int> c(10);
}
```

Or if possible, pass the size as a template parameter :

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class MyContainer{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> myArray;
    int size = N;
    MyContainer() : myArray(new T[N]) { }
};

int main() {
  MyContainer<int, 10> c;
}
```

Or, if possible, just **use `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>`**

**Notes:**

- Variable lengths arrays are non standard.
- You should initialize class members in their order of declaration.
- The size should be an `unsigned` (`std::size_t`)

Comment: In my example I was trying to see how to initialize smart pointers by constructor so it is not destroyed when leaving it's scope. I already tried myArray(new T[n]) but in the constuctor body, not in the initialization list. That was my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>
class MyContainer{
public:
    unique_ptr<T[]> myArray;
    int size;
    MyContainer(int n) : size(n), myArray(new T[n]) {}
};
```

The smart-pointer must use the array deallocator, otherwise it's UB, though in the case of trivial types probably the same code.

Take a look here for the whole [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) interface.

Comment: That is what I was looking for - a way to initialize smart pointer later on by constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you, but you really should. Programmers are often surprised to discover that if a constructor throws an exception (which is the recommended way to signal that an object can't be created for any reason), **the destructor is not run**, because there's no general way for the compiler to know which lines in the destructor correspond to which lines in the constructor.

On the other hand, any objects that have been created **are** destroyed because there is a general way to know which ones need to be destroyed.  To put it another way, if your object had two raw pointers, and the first call to `new` succeeded, but the second failed, the destructor wouldn't be run, and the first pointer would never be `delete`d. But if your object had two smart pointers, and the first was constructed successfully and the second failed, the first smart pointer **would** be properly destroyed and you wouldn't have to worry about it.